# I need to change import url in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

i need to change import url 
from this
`import { IBrand } from '../../../../@core/data';`
to this
`import { IBrand } from '@app/@core/data';`

My senior said the `@app` is better but i don't understand why it's better and how to do it please help

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      { "name": "tslint-language-service"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your TS config.json and folder structure

Comment: ```{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      { "name": "tslint-language-service"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your tsconfig file under paths:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@app/@core": ["src/app/@core"], // here
      "@app/@core/*": ["src/app/@core/*"],
      "@app/environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    },
    ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Why is this better? If you change the location structure of files, you do not have to update the import paths, which also creates a lot of unnecessary git changes.

Also, you can add more than one path for the same import if necessary:

```
paths: {
    "@app/@core": ["src/app/@core", "src/app/@otherpath"]
}
```

No, let's say you have this import:

```
import { AppService } from 'app/@core/services';
```

and your config is:

```
paths: {
  "@app/@core": ["src/app/@core", "src/app/@otherpath"]
}
```

if you move it to `src/app/@core/nested-folder`, the only thing you need to change is:

```
paths: {
  "@app/@core": ["src/app/@core/nested-folder", "src/app/@otherpath"]
}
```

or also keep the old one:

```
paths: {
  "@app/@core": ["src/app/@core", "src/app/@core/nested-folder", "src/app/@otherpath"]
}
```

Your import statement remains the same.